# Class flash.display3D::Context3D could not be found?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, starling-framework

I have downloaded the example of Adobe for using Starling at: http://www.whacksite.com/ from GitHub.
Then, I created a project **AIR AS3 project** with the **SDK 4.5.1, AIR 3.0**.

I have compiled the game, and it worked, but, when I click *"Start New Game"* at the game menu, I get the error:

> `[Fault] exception, information=VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flash.display3D::Context3D could not be found.`

In the program settings, at Flash Viewer, External Player Path is:

> D:\work\Flash\flex_sdk_4.5.1\runtimes\player\11\flashplayer_11_sa_debug_32bit.exe

I am using Flash Develop 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the swf version to 13.

In Flash Builder, you would do this by adding `-swf-version=13` to the additional compiler options.
I believe *Flash Develop* has a similar feature.

You also have to use the **AIR 3.0 namespace** in the AIR application descriptor file.

Comment: that was correct, but, didn't solve the problem until I compiled the project without running it, then, I drag drop the project swf at flaash player 11, and it worked!